# Incorrect Output From 7805

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, debugging

I am powering a few op-amps from a split supply made from a 7805 and 7905. Before connecting the amps, I measured the outputs from both regulators and got 5V and -5V, respectively. However, after I soldered down the amps, I observe -0.9V at the 7805 output pin (the 7905 functions properly). The 7805 is not getting hot, and I am not measuring any shorts between 5V and -5V, 5V and GND, or -5V and GND. I am measuring 7.5V at the input to the 7805, as expected. I tried replacing the part as well, but this behavior persisted. When I remove the 7805 and connect a benchtop supply in its place, the circuit functions as expected and my supply reads a current draw of about 100mA. I am not sure what else to check. How can I go about solving this?

The schematic is as follows, duplicated 5 times:

Edit: Yes, I know the pinout for the 7905 is wrong. I have rerouted the pins to the correct traces on the board itself, and the 7905 functions properly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: so, you've got a schematic of your load, but not a schematic containing the 7805 – but that would be the interesting one! Also, seriously, there's better voltage regulators than the good ol' 7805 series.

Comment: Oops - edited with updated schematic! I'm sure there are, but this is mainly for a proof-of-concept design. Such refinement will come later.

Comment: See the note on the data sheet regarding "operation with a load common to a voltage of opposite polarity"

Comment: @JohnBirckhead can you refer me to the datasheet you are seeing this in? there are many 7805 datasheets and I can't find the one with this note.

Comment: How do you supply +/-7.5VDC

Comment: @MarkoBuršič wall warts.

Comment: But how? Many of them? Connected ground...? Have you tried your bench supply as input voltage. 7.5V can be also critically low value.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The 7805 is powered from one single 7.5V 1A wall wart. Trying bench supply as input now, so far no good

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Tried using benchtop supply as an input; same results, even with an input as high as 9V.

Comment: Check the area around the 7805 for solder bridges. It sounds as though that's the problem, and when you desoldered the 7805 to apply the bench supply you fixed it.

Comment: I checked under a microscope and using a continuity test with a multimeter. There are none. What do you mean I fixed it? I tried resoldering the 7805 and the results persisted.

Comment: DId you check pin 2 is really grounded?

Comment: @Trevor yes, there is continuity between pin 2 and gnd.

Comment: Try fly wiring the 7805 out of the board

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems @JohnBirckhead has hit the nail on the head.

You need to add a diode to the output of the LM7805 to ground. The [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf) suggests a 1N400x, but I would use something like a [1N5819](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds23001.pdf) Schottky diode which will prevent almost all current from getting into the substrate diodes.

[image]

The effect you are seeing is likely caused by the output terminal being pulled below ground (something that can't happen easily when you don't have a negative supply). Likely that shuts the regulator output down by some internal sneak paths through the substrate isolation diodes.

I usually put diodes like the datasheet suggests into such supplies as a matter of course, even when they are sequenced up and down. Cheap insurance against strange happenings. Often you can use a small dual like [BAT54S](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds11005.pdf) and protect both regulators.

Incidentally, this behavior may well vary from one supplier to another of the 7805 chip. It's outside the normal range of operation. In a quick test, I was unable to duplicate the behavior OP is seeing even with -200mA applied to the output (Motorola part). OP's part number is apparently ST, which has this warning about "latch-up problems" in the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/41/4f/b3/b0/12/d4/47/88/CD00000444.pdf/files/CD00000444.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000444.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Was it an ST part?

Answer (score 0):

Your pinout is wrong; the 79xx and 78xx don't have input, output and ground on the same pins, but in your schematic, they do.

Comment: Yes, my bad I left this out - I know that the pinout for the 7905 is wrong, but I rewired it to correct it on the board. It is functioning as expected.